# DateTimeOffset and UTC

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, datetime, utc, datetimeoffset

I'm developing a web application and need to account for different time zones so I've been looking into using datetimeoffset in .net and mssql.  Since the clients can be in a different time zone than the server I will be storing them as UTC.  When saving the UTC the offset is always set to +0 and since the time is generated server side I can't depend on getting the offset from the client.  So I wonder, would there be any benefit in using datetimeoffset or should I just stick with datetime?

Comment: Converting it is no problem, it's more an issue of choosing and storing the correct data type.

Comment: `datetimeoffset` is not DST aware, so if you need to support time zones that observe DST, add a variable. Store UTC and then have a preference somewhere that indicates what time zone to convert to at query time. You can use [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql) for that, which is much more reliable than `datetimeoffset` IMHO.

Comment: +1 @AaronBertrand You rarely care about the offset at which the time was generated. You sometimes care about the timezone.  But as Aaron points out, datetimeoffset doesn't store the timezone, just the numeric offset.

Comment: Thanks guys.  It looks like using a datetimeoffset will probably not give me what I'm looking for in this situation.  This is more or less the answer I'm looking for, so this question can probably be closed out.